# Server hangs when rtmclient starts

Tags: python, slack

I need to receive messages from `slack` and save them to the database.
I read that this can be done through `rtmclient`. But when I try to implement this, the server just hangs on this line - `Performing system checks.`

```
slack_token = 'Bot User OAuth Access Token'
rtmclient = slack.RTMClient(token=slack_token)

@slack.RTMClient.run_on(event='message')
def say_hello(**payload):
    pass


rtmclient.start()
```

Comment: What Python version? what slackclient version? btw you can also use events to get messages.

Comment: `python 3.6`. 
I heard about the events, but either I'm doing something wrong or they don’t work.